# How to Handle Server Side Exceptions in Jquery File Upload Plugin by blueimp

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, blueimp, jquery-file-upload

I am using blueimp [jquery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) control in my mvc 4 Project its working fine but the issue is when I get server side exceptions this control does not respond at all.

My js code for handling server side exceptions is

```
$("#fileupload").bind('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
    $("#tblPresentation").find('div.progress').find('div:eq(0)').css('width', '0px');
    $("#tblPresentation").find('tr.template-upload').css('display','none');       
    $("#divGlobalProgress").html("");      
});
```

but this event also fires when I click on the cancel upload button (shown [here](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)).

So how can I handle my server side exceptions ?